# Python Serial Read Not Working

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I am attempting to control a projector using RS232 from python. This link has the needed information about the port settings and expected responses.  http://www.audiogeneral.com/Optoma/w501_rs232.pdf

To summerise it 
baud = 9600, 
Data bits = 8, 
No parity, 
1 stop bit, 
no flow control.

when the command "~00124 1\r" is sent the projector should respond okn where n is the power state.

when the command "~0000 1\r" is sent the projector should power on

From Putty I am able to send the power on command and other commands and see that the projector does what it is supposed to. I can also send the read command and get the appropriate okn response back to putty.

From python I can send the power on command and see the projector power on. however when I send the power state command I never see any character come into the read buffer.

Here is the code for a test script i wrote trying to debug this.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0")

print ser.baudrate
print ser.bytesize
print ser.parity
print ser.stopbits
print ser.xonxoff
print ser.rtscts
print ser.dsrdtr 
print ser.name

print "Power State"
ser.write("~00124 1")

while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
  response = ser.read(3)
  print response


output:
9600
8
N
1
False
False
False
/dev/ttyUSB0
True
Power State
```

I expect an okn after the power state line but it does not show up

Comment: I don't see anything print after "Power State" which suggests that ser.inWaiting()  return is <= 0, so you should print it and it's type() as it may be a string not an int.

Comment: I Printed that its type is int but its value is 0 so the loop wont run.  I tried it with while True: and it just hangs until I kill the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putty emulate a serial terminal, like minicom in Linux/Unix or HyperTerminal on Windows.
Try adding \n\r at the end of the string to act as a real serial terminal.

I suggest you to try reading your data byte per byte instead of 3 bytes at time. Better if you use readline method.

Comment: don't think readine will work since as best I can tell the projector does not send\n  to cause a new line it only sends \r after the characters.  Ill try 1 byte and adding \n to the write statement now

Comment: The \r was part of the problem I also had to add a time.sleep(0.05) between the write and the read to give the projector time to respond

Comment: You can also try setting port timeout to None, which cause all read calls to be blocking. In this way yout python script will wait until at least n bytes ar received. Try also calling method flush on serial port to ensure that all bytes are sent before calling the read method